# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

What i want to accomplish, is to be able to write SQL statements and verify the results.
The SQL Statements would have variables in them, like :

```
String sql = "Select  zoneid from zone where zonename = myZoneName";
```

Where myZoneName is generated from count +

Note: I use Apache POI to parse Excel Spreadsheet.

here is the code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

public class VerifyDBSingleDomain {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VerifyDBSingleDomain.class.getName());

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@a.b.c.d:1521:mname";

    @Test
    public void VerifyDBSingleDomainTest() throws SQLException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "user");
        props.setProperty("password", "password");

        String sql = "Select  zoneid from zone where zonename = 99224356787.tv";
        //String sql = "Select * from zone";

        Connection conn;
        //try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
            PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
            System.out.println(result);

            /*while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

    //  }
    //}

    }
}
```

and i get error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Comment: Not sure but looks like you have to quote your comparison `String sql = "Select  zoneid from zone where zonename = '99224356787.tv'";`

Comment: @gtgaxiola
not sure how you see '' for zone name, i removed it as it was a typo in the question perhaps.

Comment: I meant 99224356787.tv is not surrounded by single quotes in your code since SQL comparisons on varchars usually are of the form `WHERE field = 'myValue'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use single quotes in your `WHERE` clause assuming `myZoneName` is a text type:

```
String sql = "Select zoneid from zone where zonename = '99224356787.tv'";
```

Use the following to display the `zoneid` assuming it is an INTEGER type:

```
while (result.next()) { 
   System.out.println(result.getInt("zoneid");
}
```

Comment: Great, now i get oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl@1506dc4. but that seems to be an Object, HOW do i get the actual Table Contents

Answer (score 0):

if myZoneName is a Varchar type you have to wrap it around quotes like this

```
        String sql = "Select  zoneid from zone where zonename = '99224356787.tv'";
```

To get the table contents:

```
ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(result);

        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getInt("zoneid")); // if zoneid is int in the db table
        }
```

refer to [Java resultSet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for more information :)